# Any issue with magnet too close to rpi?

Tags: pi-3, hardware, raspicam

I don't think this is an issue, but a search turns up nothing and I just want to be sure.

I'm working on a project that involves a single speaker mounted approx. 2.5 to 3cm above a Raspberry Pi 3. The magnet (facing the rpi) on the back of said speaker is 4cm in diameter. My project includes an rpi camera, the ribbon of which brushes right up against the magnet. I intend to add some LEDs and capacitive buttons which may be placed beside the speaker.

I want the speaker positioned about like this:
[image]

Here's another picture of the speaker:
[image]
My question is this. Will the speaker magnet interfere in any significant way with the operation of my raspberry pi or attached devices?

Comment: Reviving this because I have the same question. How has it faired?